# Mesh Wire opening size for EMI filter at frequency of 30 MHz

Tags: dc-dc-converter, emc, interference

I want to use a mesh wire and I wanted to know how do I calculate an opening size of a mesh wire that can filter 30 MHz frequency.

Comment: Depends on material,  thickness, gap and attenuation needed but about 100x bigger than the exact screen type in microwave ovens

Comment: Please provide a method of calculation. I have an aluminum mesh wire of 1inch opening size, thickness of 0.12inch, and  30Mhz signal noise.

Comment: How much filtering/attenuation do you want?  In general, for a given material, the smaller the openings, the greater the attenuation.

Comment: In addition to the above, it really matters a lot about the freedom that electrons have in moving in response to EM stimulation. So the conductivity at connection points in the mesh also matter, along with other factors.

Comment: I will try testing mesh with smaller opening size, and see if it reduces the noise.

Comment: What else is important in your missing specs?  Air  flow? cost? DFM? Size?  The only Faraday Cage I bought was used by Stanley RF door in Mfg and made by Lindgren with double wall copper mosquito size screen with Berillium copper door fingers etc. 80's technology. used in 90's with >> -100 dB rating. But also having done EMI testing in a Faraday cage lab for FCC, there is a cavity resonance and with harmonics.

Comment: But doubling the signal at resonance is nothing compared to the Null signal to the Field strength meter antenna that makes the 1kW RF AMP + sweep generator hum at full power . I immediately stopped the test to limit power and notified  Lab of design fault. Null feedback cause full Interference power output.  But aside from this anecdote. What is YOUR PURPOSE?

Answer (score -1):

What matters is HOW FAR INSIDE THE MESH you place your sensitive circuits.

If you have 1" holes and you are 1" away from the hole, you get 6.28 nepers attenuation.

Richard Feynman wrote about this, in volume TWO of his lectures.